# How can I pick every line of a file with a match and do operations with it?

Tags: bash, awk

I am working on a benchmark after mining with [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/). This is a simple bash script. I save the log of terminal on txt file. I need to find every line with, in the third field, the write "Commit". I found it with the command

```
awk /'new mining work/ {print $2,$3}' /home/ubuntu/geth-general/node1.txt
```

The result is similar to this:

```
[06-03|12:15:19.020] Commit
[06-03|12:15:20.009] Commit
[06-03|12:15:21.008] Commit
[06-03|12:15:22.003] Commit
[06-03|12:15:23.011] Commit
[06-03|12:15:24.009] Commit
[06-03|12:15:25.005] Commit
[06-03|12:15:26.006] Commit
[06-03|12:15:27.005] Commit
[06-03|12:15:28.010] Commit
[06-03|12:15:29.017] Commit
```

I need to save every timestamp line as a variable and find the successive line (thanks to time). I was thinking about a FOR loop but I can't select a single line.

I tried with the feature of awk "NR" but doesn't show any results.

```
awk /'new mining work/ {if(NR==5) print $2,$3}' /home/ubuntu/geth-general/node1.txt

awk /'new mining work/ && NR==3 {print $2,$3}' /home/ubuntu/geth-general/node1.txt
```

I expect an output of:

```
[06-03|12:18:37.014] Commit
```

for example, so then I can put it into a variable and process, to proceed with the next, for example

```
[06-03|12:18:38.016] Commit
```

Comment: does `commit` ever show up in a field that isn't the third? if it doesn't,  `grep` will be your friend here

Comment: so can I grep, for instance, a $x line in a for cicle?

Comment: I do not understand what you just said. I reccomend reading the man page for grep.

Comment: To get help writing a script to pull information from a file you need to at a minimum show us the file, not the output of some other command run against the file. What you've done so far is like asking your mechanic to fix the oil leak in your car but only showing him the oil, not the car. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output to get help. Do not expect anyone to know what `mining with Geth` means - sounds like something you might do in dungeons and dragons....

Comment: pluse-uno for showing code that you have tried. Please update Q with expected output from that stream (original input would be good too). Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find the fifth line that matches and print that line and all subsequent matching lines:

```
awk '/new mining work/ && ++count >= 5 {print $2,$3}' /home/ubuntu/geth-general/node1.txt
```

This pre-increments the count variable (because of short-circuit evaluation, only when the regex match succeeds).

You can use that `count` variable to test a range as well:

```
awk '/new mining work/ && ++count >= 5 && count <=23 {print $2,$3}' /home/ubuntu/geth-general/node1.txt
```

This will stop printing after the 23rd time a match is found.

Note that I corrected the position of the opening single quote.

Comment: @fennisosa777 This solution counts the matching lines. Your `NR` attempt counts all lines, also the lines without `new mining work`. Compare `seq 1 40 | awk '/3/ && ++count==3 {print}'` with `seq 1 40 | awk '/3/ && NR==3 {print}'`

Comment: @WalterA Also try both with `seq 0 40`. That's more like one of the OP's attempts in that it prints nothing - since the regex-matched line isn't the third line in the input.